# How to solve 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libcamera._libcamera'' when using cx-freeze?

Tags: cx-freeze, python-3.9

First, I'm on python 3.9.2, cx-freeze 6.1.0 and Raspberry PI 4 bullsyes 64 bits and with an PI camera module v3.

I tried to create a distribution of my project. First I tried with PInstaller but it didn't work because PInstaller didn't detect QGLPicamera even if I specify it in the hiddenImport. So now, I try with cx-freeze but when I execute the executable there is the output :

```
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 130, in run
    module_init.run(name + "__main__")
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/console.py", line 16, in run
    exec(code, module_main.__dict__)  # pylint: disable=exec-used
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/SESA 6.0.0/src/elec_interface.py", line 2, in <module>
    from import_lib import *
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/SESA 6.0.0/src/import_lib.py", line 77, in <module>
    from picamera2 import Picamera2,Preview
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import libcamera
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libcamera/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._libcamera import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libcamera._libcamera'
```

I don't know why it didn't detect libcamera there is no documentation on it, and even if I try to specify libcamera to the packages it still doesn't work. I also try to take the .pyc generate by PYinstaller for the libcamera and put him in the packages in /distrib but it doesn't work too. When I run the generation of the distrib there are a folder '/libcamera' with a **init**.pyc file in it but nothing more. I'm not an expert of this and I'm really stuck, did somebody have an idea of what can I do ?

Here the setup.py file  :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

options= {
    'build_exe':{
        'packages' : ['libcamera'],
        'build_exe' : '../dist/',
    }
}

setup(
    name = "SESA",
    version = "6.0",
    description = "",
    options = options,
    executables = [Executable("main.py")]
)
```

Thanks in advance,